# Nikon D-750 autofocus not working

Tags: nikon, autofocus

The autofocus doesn't work on my 2 year old Nikon D-750.  Doesn't work with any of my lenses.  The AF is set on both the camera body and lens.

Comment: If you set it to manual, do you get the AF confirmation beep when you adjust focus by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Back Button focus?
As silly as it sounds, I have enabled/disabled it before and forgotten which way the camera was set up...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is broke. Take it or send it to someone that knows how to fix it.